# Azure DevOps CI / CD not installing latest flutter version

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, flutter-state, flutter-release

My Azure DevOps configuration ask CI / CD to install latest version of flutter as you can see in the snapshot:

[image]

But Flutter old stable version "2.2.1-stable" is getting install

[image]

> It seems google has changed their flutter download url so Azure not
> able to fetch latest version:
>
> Download URL Flutter Stable 2.2.1 (OLD release URL):
> https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/macos/flutter_macos_2.2.1-stable.zip
>
> Download URL Flutter Stable 2.5.1 (New Release URL):
> https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/macos/flutter_macos_2.5.1-stable.zip
>
> They have not added any new release on the old URL so Azure fetching
> always last stable release which is 2.2.1

[image]

> Any solutions so Azure DevOps script can download always latest
> version of Flutter?

Answer (score 4):

The extension [aloisdeniel/vsts-flutter-tasks](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/vsts-flutter-tasks) seems to be not mantained. Please try use this one [Fluttter install](https://github.com/hey24sheep/azure-flutter-tasks) - link to extension is [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Hey24sheep.flutter).

Please take a [look here also](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/vsts-flutter-tasks/issues/89)

> Just if you stumble across this package. It doesn't seem maintained. Someone was so kind and improved it and is also maintaining it currently. See https://github.com/hey24sheep/azure-flutter-tasks

Comment: Solution worked, Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest version you can use:

```
 - script: |
      brew install --cask flutter
```